# Jmeter - script recording

Tags: jmeter

I am new to Jmeter and trying to learn it on my own. I am setting up proxy setting in the browser and trying to record the script. But as soon I set the proxy in the browser, am not able to access the internet through that browser.Which is preventing me from recording to the script?

Kindly help me with this issue.

[image]

Comment: Did you press "Start" button in "Test script recorder"? Follow this document step by step https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf . It should work. If you have a company proxy to access internet, try installing cntlm so you can redirect jmeter http proxy (defined in your broswer) to company proxy.

Comment: Use `Port:8888`  instead of `8080`

Answer (score 0):

1. Starting from JMeter 3.0 default port for the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) is `8888`
2. The easiest way to get JMeter configured for recording is using [JMeter Templates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature) feature. From JMeter's main menu choose:

   ```
   File -> Templates -> Recording -> Create
   ```

   [image: Recording Template]
3. Don't forget to start JMeter Proxy Server

   - Expand "Workbench"
   - Select "HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder"
   - Click "Start" button
   - You will see a message regarding `Root CA Certificate` - it is OK, just information regarding JMeter generated a dummy certificate - `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt`. If you will need to record the site which uses HTTPS - you will need to import it into your browser

   [image: Start proxy]